# Name for a two vector laplacian-like operator?

Tags: laplacian

In the arXive paper [Control Functionals for Monte Carlo Integration](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1410.2392.pdf),
$\S$ 2.3.1 presents theorem $1$ on p. 7:

> Assume $\phi\in\mathcal{H}^{d}$ and $(A1,3)$. Then $\psi$ belongs to $\mathcal{H}_{0}$, the reproducing kernel Hilbert space with kernel $$
> k_{0}(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{x}'):= 
> \nabla_{x} \cdot \nabla_{x'} k(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{x}')
> + \mathbf{u}(\mathbf{x})\cdot\nabla_{x'} k(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{x}')
> + \mathbf{u}(\mathbf{x}') \cdot \nabla_{x} k(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{x}')
> + \mathbf{u}(\mathbf{x}) \cdot  \mathbf{u}(\mathbf{x}') k(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{x}')
> $$

There is a term

$$ 
\nabla_{x} \cdot \nabla_{x'} k(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{x}')
$$

where $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{x}'$ are two equal sized vectors.

Does this $\nabla_{x} \cdot \nabla_{x'} f(x,x')$ operator have a name?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: I have tried to improve the readability of your question by introducing [Tex](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/). It is possible that I unintentionally changed the meaning of your question. Please proofread the question to ensure this has not happened.

Comment: Thanks for joining Mathematics StackExchange. This quick MathJax guide will help you type set your questions: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference. You may also enjoy the tour: https://math.stackexchange.com/tour